# Node JS two foreach unexpected

Tags: node.js

I have two array from database, this is a sample.
I try to do something in the foreach, but the answer is not I expected.

Why the conso.log print sequence are not

> out loop 0 
>   in loop 0
>   in loop 1
>   in loop 2
>   in loop 3
>   in loop 4
>   out loop 1 
>   in loop 0
>   in loop 1
>   in loop 2
>   in loop 3
>   in loop 4
>   .
>   .
>   .

[My Code]

```
modules.dbCmder.query(DefaultDB, DefaultDB, strSQL, [], function (data) {
        data.forEach(function (value, index, array) {
            console.log('out loop ' + index);
            modules.dbCmder.query(DefaultDB, DefaultDB, strSQL2, [], function (res) {
                data.forEach(function (value, index, array) {
                    console.log('in loop ' + index);
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

[Code Result]

```
out loop 0
out loop 1
out loop 2
out loop 3
out loop 4
in loop 0
in loop 1
in loop 2
in loop 3
in loop 4
in loop 0
in loop 1
in loop 2
in loop 3
in loop 4
in loop 0
in loop 1
in loop 2
in loop 3
in loop 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, Javascript is putting the `modules.dbCmder.query` function call on the event stack, and then moving on in the current `forEach()`. So the outer `forEach()` runs until completion, while the 4 calls to `query` are stacked up, and then resolve in turn. That is the answer to "why" this is happening.

The solution for you would be to run a control flow library, like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) to ensure the `query` is resolved before the next outer `forEach`.

Something like

```
async.eachSeries( data, function(item, eachCb){
  console.log('out loop on item ' + item);
  modules.dbCmder.query(DefaultDB, DefaultDB, strSQL2, [], function (res) {
    data.forEach(function (value, index, array) {
      console.log('in loop ' + index);
    });
    eachCb();
  });
}, function( err ){
console.log("Processing done.");
});
```